# Is port 80 on a web server a passive socket?

Tags: sockets, ports

My question is very simple and straight to the point. In my readings, is it okay to say that the port 80 on a web server is a passive socket that simply creates an active socket for every connection?

Comment: Perhaps this question would be more suitable for Server Fault or Superuser.

Comment: @NigelNquande In what way? It is much more a programming question than one of system administration.

Comment: Well, it does deal with servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server is a passive listener (listening on a specific port), and will create a new socket when accept a new connection with unreserved port number.

For example web server (TCP server)

Listen on port 80 and accept many connections on different ports (e.g has 5 accepted sockets on port 5001, 5002, 5003, 5004, 5005)

Comment: It does not assign a new port. The accepted socket uses the same port as the listening socket.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it okay to say that the port 80 on a web server is a passive socket

It is a passive port. It is represented inside the web server process by a socket.

> that simply creates an active socket for every connection?

Ports don't create sockets. TCP creates sockets. The web server process accepts a connection and this is delivered to the process in the form of an active socket.